# excel compare current time value from sheet1 to time value range from sheet2

Tags: excel

I am trying to compare the time value from sheet 1 to sheet 2 and get the close match values in sheet1 -- B, C, D columns. Whenever I refresh the cell A it should automatically update the results in B, C, C, D see expected result

Sheet 1 show current time i.e., cell A1 "=now()"

```
    Sheet1
----------------------------------------------------
|   A           |   B       |   C       |   D       |
|---------------------------------------------------
|   12:55:00    |           |           |           |
----------------------------------------------------
```

In sheet 2, data available in 4 columns as below

```
   --------------------------------------------------------
|   No  |   Start       |   End         |   Date        |
|-------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   07:36:00    |   08:23:10    |   15/05/2015  | 
|   2   |   08:23:10    |   09:10:20    |   15/05/2015  |
|   3   |   09:10:20    |   09:57:30    |   15/05/2015  |
|   4   |   09:57:30    |   10:44:40    |   15/05/2015  |
|   5   |   10:44:40    |   11:31:50    |   15/05/2015  |
|   6   |   11:31:50    |   12:19:00    |   15/05/2015  |
|   7   |   12:19:00    |   13:06:10    |   15/05/2015  |
|   8   |   13:06:10    |   13:53:20    |   15/05/2015  |
|   9   |   13:53:20    |   14:40:30    |   15/05/2015  |
|   10  |   14:40:30    |   15:27:40    |   15/05/2015  |
|   11  |   15:27:40    |   16:14:50    |   15/05/2015  |
|   12  |   16:14:50    |   17:02:00    |   15/05/2015  |
|   13  |   17:02:00    |   18:14:50    |   15/05/2015  |
|   14  |   18:14:50    |   19:27:40    |   15/05/2015  |
|   15  |   19:27:40    |   20:40:30    |   15/05/2015  |
|   16  |   20:40:30    |   21:53:20    |   15/05/2015  |
|   17  |   21:53:20    |   23:06:10    |   15/05/2015  |
|   18  |   23:06:10    |   00:19:00    |   16/05/2015  |
|   19  |   00:19:00    |   01:31:50    |   16/05/2015  |
|   20  |   01:31:50    |   02:44:40    |   16/05/2015  |
|   21  |   02:44:40    |   03:57:30    |   16/05/2015  |
|   22  |   03:57:30    |   05:10:20    |   16/05/2015  |
|   23  |   05:10:20    |   06:23:10    |   16/05/2015  |
|   24  |   06:23:10    |   07:36:00    |   16/05/2015  |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected

Sheet1 - if the current time is 12:55:00 on 15/05/2015

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   A           |   B       |   C           |   D           |       E       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|---------------|
|   12:55:00    |   7       |   12:19:00    |   13:06:10    |   15/05/2015  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sheet1 - if the current time is 03:55:00 on 16/05/2015

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   A           |   B       |   C           |   D           |       E       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|---------------|
|   12:55:00    |   21      |   02:44:40    |   03:57:30    |   16/05/2015  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

for numbers I using the below formula but not sure how to achieve in case of time

```
=INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-D1)),ABS(A1:A20-D1),0))
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the "times" are really on different days but you want to treat them as all being on the same day.  That is, if you switch the format to a full date, they would be on different days?

Comment: Your edit has me confused now.  Why does the 2nd example go to 2:44 when there is a 3:57 on the same day?  And the 1st one goes to 12:19 when there is a 13:06 which is closer?  Or do you want closest without going over?  Finally, if you know the date, just add it to the time and use your normal formula.  Dates are numbers; it will work.  Even easier if your times already have the date and are just formatted as times.  Also, if you want closest without going over, you can simply use `MATCH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Byron, based on your solution, got an idea and implemented and achieved the desired output see my solution below

Sheet1 convert cell A1 value to number format enter in cell B1

```
 =(A1-INT(A1))*24
```

In Sheet2 convert cell B to number format -> cell D

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|   A   |   B           |   C           |   D           |
|---------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   07:36:00    |   08:23:10    |   7.6         | forumla "=(B12-INT(B12))*24"
|   2   |   08:23:10    |   09:10:20    |   8.386111111 |
|   3   |   09:10:20    |   09:57:30    |   9.172222222 |
|   4   |   09:57:30    |   10:44:40    |   9.958333333 |
|   5   |   10:44:40    |   11:31:50    |   10.74444444 |
|   6   |   11:31:50    |   12:19:00    |   11.53055556 |
|   7   |   12:19:00    |   13:06:10    |   12.31666667 |
|   8   |   13:06:10    |   13:53:20    |   13.10277778 |
|   9   |   13:53:20    |   14:40:30    |   13.88888889 |
|   10  |   14:40:30    |   15:27:40    |   14.675      |
|   11  |   15:27:40    |   16:14:50    |   15.46111111 |
|   12  |   16:14:50    |   17:02:00    |   16.24722222 |
|   13  |   17:02:00    |   18:14:50    |   17.03333333 |
|   14  |   18:14:50    |   19:27:40    |   18.24722222 |
|   15  |   19:27:40    |   20:40:30    |   19.46111111 |
|   16  |   20:40:30    |   21:53:20    |   20.675      |
|   17  |   21:53:20    |   23:06:10    |   21.88888889 |
|   18  |   23:06:10    |   00:19:00    |   23.10277778 |
|   19  |   00:19:00    |   01:31:50    |   0.316666667 |
|   20  |   01:31:50    |   02:44:40    |   1.530555556 |
|   21  |   02:44:40    |   03:57:30    |   2.744444444 |
|   22  |   03:57:30    |   05:10:20    |   3.958333333 |
|   23  |   05:10:20    |   06:23:10    |   5.172222222 |
|   24  |   06:23:10    |   07:36:00    |   6.386111111 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Now **Sheet1 C1** enter the array forumla (shift + Ctrl + Enter)

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A12:A35,MATCH(MIN(ABS(Sheet2!D12:D35-Sheet1!B1)),ABS(Sheet2!D12:D35-Sheet1!B1),0))
```

**Sheet1 D1**

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet2!A12:C35,2,FALSE)
```

**Sheet1 E1**

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet2!A12:C35,3,FALSE)
```

Output in Sheet1

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   A           |   B               |   C           |   D           |       E       |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|
|   07:36:58    |   7.615991667     |   1           |   07:36:00    |   08:23:10    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that your dates are entered from different days but you want to treat them as though they are all on the same day, you just need to subtract off the days part before doing the comparison.

Since Excel stores dates as days with the decimal representing the hours/seconds, you can simply subtract off the integer part of the value.

Here is that formula.  This is an array formula, entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

```
=INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-INT(A1:A20)-D1+INT(D1))),ABS(A1:A20-INT(A1:A20)-D1+INT(D1)),0))
```

For `A1:A20` we subtract off `INT(A1:A20)`.  Same thing for `D1` except `D1` is already being subtracted, so the `INT` part gets added back in.